# C# console project cannot add reference to EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a C#3.5 console project.
I cannot find the `System.Data.Entity` in my `Add Reference`. The image tells.
It seems that all .NET 3.5 are missing. Or is .NET 3.5 designed not to be referenced in a console project?

[image]

Edit: My Property page. I still cannot get EF referenced.
[image]

Comment: Is this Visual Studio 2010 or 2008?

Answer (score 4):

By default when you create a new Console Application in VS2010 the `Target Framework` will be `.NET Framework 3.5/4.0 Client Profile`. Go to the project properties and change it to `.NET Framework 3.5/4.0` You will now be able to add the reference to EF.

If that does not work, as Rob said, ensure you have .Net Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1/Visual Studio 2008 SP 1 installed on your PC http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22

Comment: The EF is included in the client profile: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx

Comment: I'm using VS2008. I edited the post to show my property page. The dropdownlist was set to 3.5, and the checkbox was not checked. I still cannot get EF referenced.

Comment: Hi, I right clicked the project and `add entity model` and the vs added the reference to `System.Data.Entity` for me automatically. But I still cannot add it directly from right click the `add reference`. That's weired. However I can run my project now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you've got the .Net Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1/Visual Studio 2008 SP 1 installed.  The first version of the Entity Framework shipped with the service pack.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22

Comment: Yes, I think so. I can use EF in my web applications.